# Find time difference in different rows with a condition

Tags: sql-server, pivot

I have a table showing statuses (working, not working) for several devices (`ordered by device desc, datetime desc`):

```
rownum device     datetime                  status
--------------------------------------------
1     device_1   2018-06-27 12:10:05.443       1
2     device_1   2018-06-27 12:02:31.467       0
3     device_1   2018-06-27 11:57:24.260       1
4     device_2   2018-06-27 11:57:24.260       1
5     device_2   2018-06-26 12:57:24.260       1
6     device_3   2018-06-26 09:57:24.260       1      
7     device_3   2018-06-25 09:57:24.260       0 
8     device_3   2018-06-26 09:57:24.260       0
9     device_3   2018-06-24 09:57:24.260       1 
10    device_4   2018-06-27 09:57:24.260       0
11    device_4   2018-06-26 09:57:24.260       0
```

I need to get the amount of time during which a device was not available (status = 0). 
So for device_1 it would be time difference between the date it was not working `(row 2)` and working `(row 1)`.

Device_2 was always working.

Device_3 broke `(row 8)` and started working `(row 6)`.

Device_4 was never working, so the amount of time would be from `(row 11)` to `(row 10)`

Query output table is to be:

```
device    amountoftimeinmins
----------------------------
device_x    0
```

I'd appreciate any help.

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using and what would be the expected result with the test data you have here?

Comment: The datetime (*please* stop using reserved words for column names) for row 8 and row 6 are identical. What would we assume a broken -> fixed sequence rather than a fixed -> broken one? Is the timing really to this granularity?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need a pivot here. You can use `LAG` window function to retrieve the previous status and datetimes for each device, then compare their minutes if it goes from `0` to `0` or from `0` to `1`.

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#DeviceStatus') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #DeviceStatus

CREATE TABLE #DeviceStatus (
    rownum INT IDENTITY,
    device VARCHAR(10),
    datetime datetime,
    status BIT)

INSERT INTO #DeviceStatus (
    device,
    datetime,
    status)
VALUES
    ('device_1',   '2018-06-27 12:10:05.443',      1),
    ('device_1',   '2018-06-27 12:02:31.467',      0),
    ('device_1',   '2018-06-27 11:57:24.260',      1),
    ('device_2',   '2018-06-27 11:57:24.260',      1),
    ('device_2',   '2018-06-26 12:57:24.260',      1),
    ('device_3',   '2018-06-26 09:57:24.260',      1),     
    ('device_3',   '2018-06-25 09:57:24.260',      0),
    ('device_3',   '2018-06-26 09:57:24.260',      0),
    ('device_3',   '2018-06-24 09:57:24.260',      1),
    ('device_4',   '2018-06-27 09:57:24.260',      0),
    ('device_4',   '2018-06-26 09:57:24.260',      0)



;WITH LaggedStatus AS
(
    SELECT
        D.*,
        LaggedStatus = LAG(D.status) OVER (PARTITION BY D.device ORDER BY D.datetime ASC),
        LaggedDatetime = LAG(D.Datetime) OVER (PARTITION BY D.device ORDER BY D.datetime ASC)
    FROM
        #DeviceStatus AS D
),
MinutesBroken AS
(
    SELECT
        L.*,
        MinutesBroken = CASE WHEN L.LaggedStatus = 0 THEN DATEDIFF(MINUTE, L.LaggedDatetime, L.datetime) END
    FROM
        LaggedStatus AS L
)
SELECT
    M.device,
    TotalMinutesBroken = ISNULL(SUM(M.MinutesBroken), 0)
FROM
    MinutesBroken AS M
GROUP BY
    M.device
```

Result:

```
device      TotalMinutesBroken
device_1    8
device_2    0
device_3    1440
device_4    1440
```

**Note**: `LAG` is for version 2012+, if you have a previous one, you can simluate lag's effect with `ROW_NUMBER()`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the clarification, please advise if I have one more column for `group` in initial table, say, group_a has devices_1-4, group_b also has devices_1-4? And this group would be In the result table. So how do I make partition by device and a group? Then the datetime differences should be within this group as well.

Comment: @GyuzalR Add these grouping columns on the LAG's PARTITION BY columns and in the final GROUP BY and it will consider each group as that list of columns. Also add them on the final select so you can see it.